# How to grep for line below another and above (or between)

Tags: linux, unix, aix

I would like to grep for a line that contains the number 638.

The output file contains the text below:

```
Please label this tape as number 1 in the arc tape sequence. 

This tape contains the following logical logs:

 638

Program over.
Done at Tue 25 Oct 2016 11:34:07 GMT
```

My aim is to grep for the number 638. Note that the number can vary across systems. I would like to grep the next line after the text "This tape contains the following logical logs:" to print the desired number line 638 or grep above "Program over." to get 638.

I tried the below and it does not work:

```
grep -A "This tape contains the following logical logs" filename | 
grep -B 1 "Program over." | grep -v "Program over."
```

`Grep -A` and `grep -B` does not work for some reason.

I get the following error message:

```
grep: Not a recognized flag: A
```

Is there an `awk` command that can be used for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sed -n '/logical/{n;n;p;}' ontape-level0.out
```

Answer (score 0):

-A (for after) and -B (for before) require a numeric argument as explained in the man page. such as:

```
grep -B 1 -A 2 "This tape contains the following logical logs" filename
```

This will grep the bloc you mentioned.

Comment: Depending on what your are looking for, you have to adjust the numbers.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

sed -n '/This tape contains the following logical logs:/{n;n;p;}' ontape-level0.out'